# Why Github don’t warn us on PR request about a branch not being updated to the destination branch?

Tags: github, git-merge

As repo reviewer you’ll get PR, review the code (semantics) and Github will simply check about merge ability of the changes.

If a (remote) collaborator works on a outdated master branch will potentially have positive feedback from tests. But might have hidden semantics issues or  might break tests when merged on the latest master commit (hopefully at CD's pipeline test phase and before going to prod).

Said so, I agree that it’s always up to the reviewers to ensure that the PR should not break.

But I’m also thinking, why not helping the reviewer by warning that you are currently merging changes starting from a branch that is behind X commits from master?

Does it make sense? Or maybe there’s already something (invisible to me) that might alert us inside a PR UI about it?

P.S. I understand that.... if the above is confirmed this is not going to be a real question but a feature request to Github... but I think it's worth questioning about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `master` branch protected and require that the branch in the PR be up to date before allowing a merge.  The [GitHub documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/enabling-required-status-checks) describes how to do this.